# Enable Windows file sharing in a switch connected network

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

There are several windows 7 PCs connecting with each other via a switch, and it's not connecting to internet.

I want to be able to deploy files on one machine to the rest. Since the network is identified as "unidentified network", I have to go to each PCs to enable file sharing under public network. I was wondering if there's any way to make it easier.

Can I set any PC's IP as default gateway in other PCs? Does this help windows to treat the network as private network? Is there any command line to enable file sharing in {public|private} network? Or any other approach is welcome too.

To make each node can share to each other is just for me convenience to deploy. Since this is closed network, so I can open to all. However, please advise if this is the right way to do it? How do people usually do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can share a drive on one of the PC's and then dump the files onto that drive.. or you can do the same on every PC on the network. Then you can access any shared drive from any PC using that PC's IP. You will also need an account with a password for accessing shares.

It is better if you set a PC's ip as default gateway. For ex. say 192.168.1.1 and then assign ip's in the range of 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.10 to the other PC's.

Usually in a network the gateway is either a router/device facing the internet.

Comment: I'd recommend against setting a non-router as the gateway.  If no routing is possible on the network, just leave the gateway blank; this will not interfere with communications within the subnet.